# How can i select rows that do not have any matching foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MainTable mt
LEFT JOIN Lookup_Items msn ON mt.Item = msn.Item_ID
WHERE msn.Item_ID is NULL
```

I have the above query that i want to use to find all rows in "MainTable" with out a matching foreign key.

Column Item in "MainTable" is of nvarchar(200) datatype but column Item_ID in table Lookup_Items is an int.

The problem i have is that if a row in MainTable does NOT have a matching foreign key, the Item column will contain string data and the above query will fail with error message

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'TestValue' to data type int.

Is there away i can work a round this so the query can execute successfully and still give me all rows with no matching foreign key?

Comment: why the data type in Maintable and Lookup_Items are different ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast the int into a string :

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MainTable mt
LEFT JOIN Lookup_Items msn ON mt.Item = CAST(msn.Item_ID as NVARCHAR(200))
WHERE msn.Item_ID is NULL
```

That way, they both will be compared as the same data type, and won't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is type of item_ID. You should convert item Id to nvarchar:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MainTable mt
LEFT JOIN Lookup_Items msn ON mt.Item = cast(msn.Item_ID as nvarchar(200))
WHERE msn.Item_ID is NULL
```